# Can't add Leaflet LayerGroup to Map

Tags: leaflet, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on a Nuxt, Leaflet, Mapboxgl project. 
This is how I init my map:

```
let mapOptions = {
    container: 'map',
    style: 'http://linkToMapStyle.com',
    attributionControl: false,
    center: [13.404954, 52.520008],
    zoom: 5,
    minZoom: 1,
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true
  };
  _this.map = new mapboxgl.Map(mapOptions);
```

I'll be loading marker data from my REST endpoint on every map moveend event. So I'll be loading and deleting markers quite a lot. That's why I wanted to use layerGroup to group all my markers so I can remove them easier.

On the map.load event I'm trying to add the layerGroup and the markers to my layerGroup:

```
var marker1 = L.marker([13.404954, 52.520008]);
var marker2 = L.marker([14.404954, 51.520008]);
var markers = L.layerGroup();
markers.addLayer(marker1);
markers.addLayer(marker2);
markers.addTo(_this.map)
```

And it's giving my errors:

```
    Error: layers.undefined: either "type" or "ref" is required 
...



 Error: layers.undefined: missing required property "source"
...



 Error: layers.undefined: missing required property "id"
..
```

All the examples I found where without specifying any type of layer options so I don't understand why this is not working for me.

Comment: You're mixing two APIs - a mapboxgl map can't use leaflet layers.

Comment: wow... how stupid. thanks so much for pointing out!

Comment: Do you maybe also know if there is a better approach then removing all of the markers by id with a for loop and the map.removeLayer() method?

Comment: Is there a way to use leaflet markers with mapbox map?